# react-native ListView line feed

Tags: android, listview, react-native

listview line feed to next line ,every line with two items, here is the datasource:

```
var data=[
        {
            "name": "test name0",
            "url": "http://someurl.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "test name1",
            "url": "http://someurl.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "test name2",
            "url": "http://someurl.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "test name3",
            "url": "http://someurl.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "test name4",
            "url": "http://someurl.com"
        }
    ]
```

I want to display it as what the red words shows: test name0 ,test name1 (then line feed and data shows at the next line). test name 2,test name3 ...
[image]

I think it might not be a difficult problem. But I just don't know how to make it . Here is the code:

```
_renderRow(rowData) {
        return (
            <View style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() =>this._pressRow(rowData.url)} underlayColor = "transparent" >
            <View>
            <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text style={styles.text}> {rowData.name} </Text>
             </View>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() =>this._pressRow(rowData.url)} underlayColor = "transparent" >
            <View>
            <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text style={styles.text}> {rowData.name} </Text>
             </View>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style = {styles.content}>
                <ListView 
                    contentContainerStyle = {styles.list}
                    pageSize={2}
                    dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
var style = StyleSheet.create({
 list: {
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    row: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingRight: 20,
        paddingTop: 50,
        paddingBottom: 50,
        margin: 10,
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderColor: '#CCC'
    },
)} ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok ,I solved it.

```
 list: {
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap' ,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width ,
    },
```

add `width` attribute to `list`. then it shows as what I want.